# Can anyone tell me how do I create a vertical line as shown in the image

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

Hello, I am designing a WordPress website. Can Somebody tell me How could I design a vertical small line as shown in the image attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is an unordered list with anchor tags?

you can do this by using the following css:

```
 ul > li > a{
   border-right: thin solid right;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
ul > li:last-child > a{
   border-right: none;
}
```